# Node.js http server not accessible from intranet

Tags: node.js, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to set up a http server that's accessible for other PCs in my company's intranet. The machine runs under Windows Server 2008R2, it has static IP and domain. It responds when I ping it from PCs connected to the intrantet.

For test purposes I'm using **http-server** npm module. When I run it, I can access the web server from the machine it runs on, but not from other machines in the same network. How can I make it accessible for PCs in my company's intranet?

Comment: Have you checked the windows Firewall configuration of your windows server? If your http-server is listening from another port that is not 80 or 8080 it probably doesn't allow the connection.

Comment: Server is listening on 8080.

Comment: Check if you have that port open in your windows firewall configuration (on the server) I think it is closed by default and you need to allow connections on that port.

Comment: It's working, thank you! Will it be accessible from outside of company's network if I applied this rule only to the Domain?

Comment: To work outside of your company's network you need to talk with the network's administrator to assign you a public ip address. He will configure the NAT or NAPT configuration in the router that is connected with the ISP.